# How to "cache" the result of controller helper methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, caching, data-processing

I'm using Ruby on Rails 7 and I've many [`helper_method`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Helpers/ClassMethods.html#method-i-helper_method)s in my ApplicationController (see code below), some of which require relatively heavy data processing to execute e.g. because they check complex parameter input data for security reasons.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method :param_heavy_processing
  helper_method :param_medium_processing
  helper_method :param_light_processing
  // ...

  private

  def param_heavy_processing
    return nil unless params[:param_heavy].present?
    // heavy data processing e.g. many iterations
  end

  def param_medium_processing
    return nil unless params[:param_medium].present?
    // medium data processing
  end

  def param_light_processing
    return nil unless params[:param_light].present?
    // light data processing
  end

 // ...
end
```

In my views and controllers I call these methods sparingly, in many cases more than once in a request flow. By logging into them, it seems that each time I call a helper method then data processing for that method is performed by scratch (again and again, once per call), which is not good for performance on the long run.

So, I thought to "cache" someway the result of the first call of these methods for the entire controller action flow in order to execute data processing only once per request. Is it possible? If so, how?

Comment: Do you want to cache the result of those methods only for the duration of the current request and the current user? Or for later requests from potentially other users too?

Comment: Just for the duration of the current request and the current user, but knowing how to make that for other users would be good too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is alternative pattern you can use for the current request. Heavy processing executes at most one time per current request even if the result returns nil.

```rb
def param_heavy_processing
  return if params[:param_heavy].blank?
  
  return @param_heavy_processing if defined? @param_heavy_processing
  @param_heavy_processing = # heavy data processing
end
```

Answer (score 2):

When you only want to cache the result of a method for the duration of the current request, then the most common pattern looks like this:

```
def param_heavy_processing
  return if params[:param_heavy].blank?
  
  @param_heavy_processing ||= begin
    # heavy data processing e.g. many iterations
  end
end
```

This stores the result of the *heavy data processing* in an instance variable on the first call. The next time the method is called, the instance variable is already set, returned immediately and the block will not be re-evaluated.

On the next request, a new instance of the controller will be created and therefore the cache in the instance variable will be gone and will need to be re-generated.

It is worth noting that this pattern doesn't work when the heavy computation might return `nil` or `false`. Then you will need more complex patterns.